# C++ error making a vector using structs

Tags: c++, string, vector, struct

I'm attempting to create a c++ program that uses a text file as a database. To do this, it stores lines in the text file (which represent songs) as "Revolution Diplo Revolution 320 12"
When that sentence is split (a whole other dilemma), the data values are name, artist, album, kilobytes/second, and size in megabytes, respectively.

I'm getting the following errors:

1. ‘main()::song’ uses local type ‘main()::song’,
2. Trying to instantiate ‘template class std::allocator’,
3. Template argument 2 is invalid, and
4. A function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

And I cannot figure out how it works at all.

```
struct song{
    string name;
    string artist;
    string album;
    string kbs;
    string size;
}; 

//Declare our function that will search
vector<song> loadStructsInData(){ //THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR ARISES
    /* this part just reads a file and interprets each line as structs, like a database */

    return songs;
    cout<<"All done!"<<endl<<endl;
}
```

And it's all in the main() function.

Comment: `main()::song` - looks like you're declaring everything within `main()`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your struct at the global (or class, but not function) scope to use it in an STL container.

Comment: So, I would just declare it outside of main? (I really am a beginner to c++, thanks though!)

Comment: @Gabriel. Yeah, declare your struct outside of your main function. Also, you are returning before `cout`, so you will never reach your `cout` statement.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question, is it possible to make a struct without attaching it to a variable name? So could I make a vector of "song" structs that have no variable name?

Comment: @Gabriel As a rule of thumb, you should try and answer 'is it possible' questions on your own through a quick trial and error. You'll learn more that way. 

As far as your question, I'm not sure what exactly you're asking. You always need to name your variables. i.e. `vector<Song> mySongs;`